# How do I find the angle between 2 forces?

Tags: geometry, vectors

If have a resultant force $F_R = (3i + j - k)$ and and component of that force is $F_1 = (2i - 2j + k)$.  How do I find the angle between these 2 forces?

Comment: Find the dot product. $\cos\theta=\frac{F_R\cdot F_1}{|F_R||F_1|}$

Comment: If the only reason you need to know the angle is so that you can use the cosine of that angle, then you can save some effort by using the dot product to find $\cos\theta$, as above, and then don't even bother to calculate $\theta$ from that, just use the value of $\cos\theta$ you already found.

Answer (score 2):

If $a$ and $b$ are vectors and the angle between them is $\alpha$, then
$$\sum a_ib_i = \langle a,b \rangle = |a||b|\cos(\alpha) $$

Answer (score 1):

Given two vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, their **dot product** can be calculated in two ways:$$\vec{a}.\vec{b}=|a|\cdot|b|\cdot\cos(\theta)\tag{1}$$$$\vec{a}.\vec{b}=\sum^ia_i\cdot b_i\tag{2}$$where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors.

Combine these two to obtain your desired result.